# Exception 'SqlException' on Windows CE (System.Data.SQLClient)

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-ce

When executing a command the following `SqlException` is given. A connection has already been established. The client OS is an emulated Windows CE querying an SQL Server 2012 database.

An exception is thrown on this line:

```
SqlDataReader reader = Shared.command.GetCommand().ExecuteReader();
```

Shared is a class of variables with initialised static objects.

### Code

```
class Connect
    {
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection();

        public SqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            return connect;
        }

        public void SetConnection(string server, string database, string user, string password)
        {
            connect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + server + "; Initial Catalog=" + database + "; User ID=" + user + "; Password=" + password + ";";
        }

        public void Open()
        {
            try
            {
                connect.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
class Command
    {
        public Command()
        {
            command.Connection = Shared.connect.GetConnection();
        }

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

        public SqlCommand GetCommand()
        {
            return command;
        }

        public void SetCommand(string commandText, List<SqlParameter> parameters)
        {
            command.CommandText = commandText;

            foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }
    }
```

---

```
List <SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("BARCODE", tbxBarcode.Text));

Shared.command.SetCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE BARCODE_STRING = @BARCODE", parameters);

IV_Barcode barcode = new IV_Barcode();
DataTable table = barcode.Execute();
```

### StackTrace

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior run, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Inventory_Checker.IV_Barcode.Execute()
   at Inventory_Checker.frmMain.tbxBarcode_LostFocus(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
   at Inventory_Checker.Program.Main()
```

Comment: use the Debugger for starters.. also wrap you Sql Objects around a `using(){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been sorted out. My SQL Parameter was the cause of the issue.

The following has to be changed ...

```
List <SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("BARCODE", tbxBarcode.Text));

Shared.command.SetCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE BARCODE_STRING = @BARCODE", parameters);

IV_Barcode barcode = new IV_Barcode();
DataTable table = barcode.Execute();
```

... to this:

```
List <SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BARCODE", tbxBarcode.Text));

Shared.command.SetCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE BARCODE_STRING = @BARCODE", parameters);

IV_Barcode barcode = new IV_Barcode();
DataTable table = barcode.Execute();
```

Comment: Yes the problem is with the parameter, you should use @BARCODE instead BARCODE.